# Exact conversion from float to int

Tags: java, data-conversion

I want to convert float value to int value or throw an exception if this conversion is not exact.

I've found the following suggestion: use `Math.round` to convert and then use `==` to check whether those values are equal. If they're equal, then conversion is exact, otherwise it is not.

But I've found an example which does not work. Here's code demonstrating this example:

```
        String s = "2147483648";

        float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
        System.out.printf("f=%f\n", f);

        int i = Math.round(f);
        System.out.printf("i=%d\n", i);

        System.out.printf("(f == i)=%s\n", (f == i));
```

It outputs:

```
f=2147483648.000000
i=2147483647
(f == i)=true
```

I understand that 2147483648 does not fit into integer range, but I'm surprised that `==` returns true for those values. Is there better way to compare float and int? I guess it's possible to convert both values to strings, but that would be extremely slow for such a primitive function.

Comment: "I'm surprised that == returns true for those values" - the `int` is being promoted to `float`, and the two float values are the same. The closest `float` value to 2147483647 is 2147483648.000000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

floats are rather inexact concepts. They are also mostly pointless unless you're running on at this point rather old hardware, or interacting specifically with systems and/or protocols that work in floats or have 'use a float' hardcoded in their spec. Which may be true, but if it isn't, stop using floats and start using `double` - unless you have a fairly large `float[]` there is **zero** memory and performance difference, floats are just less accurate.

Your algorithm cannot fail when using `int` vs `double` - **all** ints are perfectly representable as `double`.

### Let's first explain your code snippet

The underlying error here is the notion of 'silent casting' and how java took some intentional liberties there.

In computer systems in general, you can only compare like with like. It's easy to put in exact terms of bits and machine code what it means to determine whether `a == b` is true or false if a and b are of the exact same type. It is not at all clear when a and b are different things. Same thing applies to pretty much any operator; `a + b`, if both are e.g. an `int`, is a clear and easily understood operation. But if `a` is a `char` and `b` is, say, a `double`, that's not clear at all.

Hence, in java, **all** binary operators that involve different types **are illegal**. In basis, there is no bytecode to directly compare a float and a double, for example, or to add a string to an int.

However, there is syntax sugar: When you write `a == b` where a and b are different types, **and** java determines that one of two types is 'a subset' of the other, then java will simply silently convert the 'smaller' type to the 'larger' type, so that the operation can then succeed. For example:

```
int x = 5;
long y = 5;
System.out.println(x == y);
```

This works - because java realizes that converting an `int` to a `long` value is not ever going to fail, so it doesn't bother you with explicitly specifying that you intended the code to do this. In JLS terms, this is called a **widening conversion**. In contrast, any attempt to convert a 'larger' type to a 'smaller' type isn't legal, you have to explicitly cast:

```
long x = 5;
int y = x; // does not compile
int y = (int) x; // but this does.
```

The point is simply this: When you write the reverse of the above (`int x = 5; long y = x;`), the code is **identical**, it's just that compiler silently injects the `(long)` cast for you, on the basis that no loss will occur. The same thing happens here:

```
int x = 5;
long y = 10;
long z = x + y;
```

That compiles *because* `javac` adds some syntax sugar for you, specifically, that is compiled as if it says: `long z = ((long) x) + y;`. The 'type' of the expression `x + y` there is `long`.

**Here's the key trick: Java considers converting an int to a float, as well as an int or long to a double - a widening conversion.**

As in, javac will just assume it can do that safely without any loss and therefore will not enforce that the programmer explicitly acknowledges by manually adding the cast. However, int->float, as well as long->double are **not actually entirely safe**.

floats can represent every integral value between -2^23 to +2^23, and doubles can represent every integral value between -2^52 to +2^52 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)). But `int` can represent every integral value between `-2^31` to `+2^31-1`, and longs `-2^63` to `+2^63-1`. That means at the edges (very large negative/positive numbers), integral values exist that are representable in ints but not in floats, or longs but not in doubles (all ints are representable in double, fortunately; `int -> double` conversion is entirely safe). But java doesn't 'acknowledge' this, which means silent widening conversions can nevertheless toss out data (introduce rounding) silently.

That is what happens here: `(f == i)` is syntax sugared into `(f == ((float) i))` and the conversion from int to float introduces the rounding.

### The solution

Mostly, when using doubles and floats and nevertheless wishing for exact numbers, you've already messed up. These concepts fundamentally just aren't exact and this exactness cannot be sideloaded in by attempting to account for error bands, as the errors introduced due to the rounding behaviour of float and double cannot be tracked (not easily, at any rate). You should not be using float/double as a consequence. Either find an atomary unit and represent those in terms of int/long, or use `BigDecimal`. (example: To write bookkeeping software, **do not** store finance amounts as a `double`. **do** store them as 'cents' (or satoshis or yen or pennies or whatever the atomic unit is in that currency) in `long`, or, use `BigDecimal` if you really know what you are doing).

### I want an answer anyway

If you're absolutely positive that using float (or even double) here is acceptable and you still want exactness, we have a few solutions.

Option 1 is to employ the power of BigDecimal:

```
new BigDecimal(someDouble).intValueExact()
```

This works, is 100% reliable (unless float to double conversion can knock a non-exact value into an exact one somehow, I don't think that can happen), and throws. It's also very slow.

An alternative is to employ our knowledge of how the IEEE floating point standard works.

A real simple answer is simply to run your algorithm as you wrote it, but to add an additional check: If the value your `int` gets is below `-2^23` or above `+2^23` then it *probably* isn't correct. However, there are still a smattering of numbers below -2^23 and +2^23 that are perfectly representable in both float and int, just, no longer every number at that point. If you want an algorithm that will accept those exact numbers as well, then it gets much more complicated. My advice is not to delve into that cesspool: If you have a process where you end up with a `float` that is anywhere near such extremes, and you want to turn them to `int` but only if that is possible without loss, you've arrived at a crazy question and you need to rewire the parts that you got you there instead!

If you really need that, instead of trying to numbercrunch the `float`, I suggest using the `BigDecimal().intValueExact()` trick if you truly must have this.